# Vertical top align figures of different height in Rmarkdown

Tags: html, r-markdown, multiple-columns, vertical-alignment, figure

I have an Rmarkdown code chunk where I want to display two external figures of different heights, and have them aligned vertically at the top. I am outputting an HTML document.

Here is the code

````
```{r, fig.show='hold', out.width="25%"}
include_graphics("leftfig.png")
include_graphics("rightfig.png")
````

This produces middle-aligned side-by-side plots (not the actual images, just used as an example).

[image]

However, I want these two figures top-aligned. I have tried various combinations of chunk options but I don't find fig.align options related to **vertical** alignment, nor do I see options for the YAML header that manages this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick workaround with CSS (applied to the entire document):

````
---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
---

```{css}
img {vertical-align: top;}
```

```{r, fig.show='hold', out.width='25%'}
knitr::include_graphics("leftfig.png")
knitr::include_graphics("rightfig.png")
```
````

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you. I thought css might be the answer - but my web-searches for the right command/format had failed. 

One minor issue is that the css seems to apply to the entire document - so if I want some top aligned, others center - this doesn't work. Regardless of this minor issue - the answer was extremely helpful. Thanks.

Comment: The only way I know that someone can programmatically set the vertical alignment of a image applied specifically to R Markdown chunk is through the [Quarto.org](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/figures.html#vertical-alignment) (the next generation of R Markdown implemented in a cross-language fashion, built on Pandoc).

Answer (score 1):

A method that allows you to set *local*, rather than *global*, vertical alignment of figures and/or images in an html output document exploits the utility of CSS styles linked to specific HTML class attributes assigned to any HTML `div` tag.

````
---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
---

<style type="text/css">
.topalign img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
</style>

<div class="topalign">
```{r, fig.show='hold', out.width='25%'}
knitr::include_graphics(c("leftfig.png", "rightfig.png"))
```
</div>
````

> Note: I've also taken the liberty to demonstrate how the `include_graphics()` function can actually take a *vector* of image paths, thus only having to call the function once per code chunk.

Once the CSS is defined at the top of the document, this `div` tag: `<div class="topalign">` ... `</div>` can be wrapped around any/multiple evaluated rmarkdown code chunks you wish to have top-aligned.

Comment: Thank you - this is a very elegant solution that also opens up many other possibilities.